# Restfull web application with oauth when client is also a website

Tags: zend-framework, session, rest, oauth

I am creating a solution that will contains a website and mobile apps. I will use Zend-Framework 2 for the website.
So, to make it good, I am wondering if it would be a good idea to build :

- A REST web service (using zf2)
- Another website that will call the REST ws (using zf2)
- The mobile apps that will call the REST ws

I will use OAuth for the autentication and security.
My question is, if my website gets the data by calling the REST ws, it will have to make a database request at each call to check the token whereas if I do a "normal" website, my app will be able to use session to store the information of the connected user.
Because, for what I have read, there is no such thing as session with OAuth/REST so for each call, I have one more sql request to check the token validity.

Is it still a good idea to make a full REST service, even for the website or to have a "normal" website and also a REST service API just for the mobile apps ?

Thanks

Comment: Jahanara's response is absolutely correct.  And to elaborate: OAuth (authentication), REST (program::program communication) and a "normal website" (users interacting with your HTML/CSS) all *complement* each other.  It's *not* an either/or proposition: you can mix'n'match these technologies as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Oauth is a server to server authentication framework. Like it is between mobile app and your API server , website vs your API server etc. You can adopt an approach where , you generate only one access token for your website client instead of multiple access token for each user from the website. This access token is stored in your webserver vs user cookie in website.Ultimately the aim is to identify all the clients of your REST WS and your website is one of its client and a very trusted one.
This way you can cache the access token to avoid db calls (typically cache time can be equal to or less than token expiry time). Do explore the multiple grant types specified in the oauth spec for this

Regarding maintaining session for user in your website, it is not dependent on whether the back end is a REST WS or not, it can be handled in your website